# Is it possible to enter the position according to the conditions of the next candle when entering the long or short?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Specifically, after breaking through with a crossover or crossunder, the next candle enters a long or short when it close with a green or a red candle.

I want to make this.

i tried this

```
yLong  = crossover(close, lower) and (close >= open)
yhort = crossunder(close, upper) and (open > close)
// Strategy entry //

if (yLong) 
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)
```

How can i decide whether to enter or not according to the next candle?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there was a cross on the previous bar by using the [history reference operator []](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

```
yLong  = (crossover(close, lower)[1]) and (close >= open)
yhort = (crossunder(close, upper)[1]) and (open > close)
```